# why the following syntax is working? I did define function layer_size() but I have not defined function layer_sizes_test_case()

Tags: python, function

Why does the following python code block work? I did define function layer_size() but I have not defined function layer_sizes_test_case().

```
def layer_sizes( X , Y ):

    n_x = X.shape[0]
    n_h = 4
    n_y = Y.shape[0]

return n_x , n_h , n_y

X_assess, Y_assess = layer_sizes_test_case()
(n_x, n_h, n_y) = layer_sizes(X_assess, Y_assess)
```

Comment: Did you import any module? The function `layer_sizes_test_case()` might be imported from another module, and that's why the code works.

Comment: The code you have posted does not behave as you describe. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is working because:

Firstly I assume you came across this code in week 3 of Andrew Ng's deeplearning (Planar data classification)

Check the import statement:

```
from testCases_v2 import *
```

this line of code imports above mentioned function:

```
def layer_sizes_test_case():
   np.random.seed(1)
   X_assess = np.random.randn(5, 3)
   Y_assess = np.random.randn(2, 3)
   return X_assess, Y_assess
```

Clink on the mentioned link Github link for the functions .py file:
[Github link](https://github.com/rvarun7777/Deep_Learning/blob/master/Neural%20Networks%20and%20Deep%20Learning/Week%203/Planar%20data%20classification%20with%20one%20hidden%20layer/testCases.py)  This GIT doesn't belongs to me. Posted here for educational purpose.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `return` needs to be inside the function `layer_sizes`. So, indent your code properly. Like this:

```
def layer_sizes( X , Y ):

    n_x = X.shape[0]
    n_h = 4
    n_y = Y.shape[0]

    return n_x , n_h , n_y
```

Anyway, I don't see anyway your code could work. It just had a syntax error that I had to let you know about. If you actually meant that the `return` should be indented to inside the function and just messed up, then I still don't see any way your code could've worked. You must have imported a module that has the function `layer_size_test_case()` or maybe you defined this function somewhere above this block of code you have posted and you must have forgot about it later. If you could provide more information, I can edit my answer to give you more support.

Comment: Yes, it was one of my modules.

Comment: Basically, I thought if you want to use a function from a module, you have to mention the name of the module before the function.